# Laravel 5.1 saving Object instance to cookie not working?

Tags: php, session, laravel, cookies

I have a segment of code which works flawlessly for me, but not for him. When a user logs in with steam, a session is created with the users steam details (steam_user object is saved to session). This session is then used in the view for things such as display name, picture, and used to determine what to show.

The problem for him is that the session cannot be accessed in the view (master.blade.php). It is not found; yet the steam session data can be dumped right after it is created in the controller, but is gone after that. He can also create a normal session with a single value, or create an array and save it to the session, but when he tries to save an object to the session it doesn't work.

How can it work for me but not for him? I pushed my project to bitbucket (including vendors), he cloned it, and it still doesn't work.

It works when he changes the Session Driver to 'file', but as a cookie it doesn't work. Chrome, Firefox and IE were tested.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jP5cvXRK

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are saving is possibly too large to be saving in a cookie using the Laravel Cookie driver.

The file driver stores the object/data as a file on your server and saves an Id/reference to that file in a cookie thus removing this limit.

Comment: Mmm seems like it might be that. We decided just to manually create the array instead of using the user object. Thanks!